# WooCommerce Hook after Billing form completed, but before payment Gateway

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, hooks

In Woocommerce, I need to call a function after than the client completed the billing form, but before the payment gateway. This function needs to use the billing form informations... Is there a Hook for that, and how can I retrieve the users infos ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This action hook is performed after submission:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'custom_woocommerce_auto_complete_order' );
function custom_woocommerce_auto_complete_order( $order_id ) { 
    echo $order_id;
}
```

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for : I need to process something after than the client clicked on the submit button, and I need to use the informations from the billing form

Comment: There is also hook woocommerce_thankyou. It is performed after submission but it doesnt have any impact on payment gateway.I have updated my answer.